# Invalid Identifier SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

So i have this:

```
SELECT p.plantnaam,o.levcode,o.offerteprijs
FROM plant p, offerte o
JOIN (SELECT plantcode , MIN(offerteprijs) AS offprijs 
      FROM offerte
      GROUP BY plantcode) s
  ON s.plantcode = p.plantcode
  AND s.offprijs = o.offerteprijs
ORDER BY p.plantnaam,l.levcode
```

Appearently on the 6th row, p.plantcode is suddenly magically an invalid identifier. Why is this? and why are all the others from the exact same table perfectly fine before that point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing JOINs. You have both implicit and explicit joins. The explicit JOIN syntax with the ON clause has a higher precedence over the implicit join with the commas. As a result the alias for the `plant` and the `offerte` tables will not be available in the ON clause. Try using the same JOIN type throughout:

```
SELECT p.plantnaam, o.levcode, o.offerteprijs
FROM 
(
  SELECT plantcode , MIN(offerteprijs) AS offprijs 
  FROM offerte
  GROUP BY plantcode
) s
INNER JOIN plant p
   ON s.plantcode = p.plantcode
INNER JOIN offerte o
   ON s.offprijs = o.offerteprijs
ORDER BY p.plantnaam, l.levcode
```

Comment: Then why does this one work perfectly?: `SELECT p.soort, p.plantnaam, p.hoogte 
FROM plant p
JOIN (SELECT soort , MAX(hoogte) AS hoogste 
      FROM plant 
      GROUP BY soort) s
  ON s.soort = p.soort
  AND s.hoogste = p.hoogte
ORDER BY p.soort
`

Comment: @Smileynator Because you are not joining tables with a comma in that one. You are using ANSI join syntax in that version.

Comment: Oh you mean in my FROM statement i have only 1 table defined instead of multiple ones?

Comment: @Smileynator Yes.  See the difference in my version versus yours. Each table and subquery is separated by a `JOIN`. The `JOIN` and `ON` is used first and since your version is using multiple tables in the `FROM` and the aliases are then not available.

Comment: I think i will never truly understand SQL, or at least these joins. However i think i can figure this one out. Ill read up a bit more about joins, they still confuse me. Thanks!

Comment: @Smileynator The best way to solve this is to always use the same syntax. :)

Comment: The syntax on SQL is ever so strict as far as i noticed in the past. However finding errors in (and understanding given errors) seems like a maze to me. It is as if Oracle never really bothered to write something for that

Comment: @Smileynator Don't get discouraged, it takes time. You will get it! :)